# Creating species distribution map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, polygon, distribution

I have to create a map for my GIS project that shows marine mammal species distribution within the UK and Ireland. The marine mammal data set is from the iucn red list and comes in the form of polygons, I also have a shapefile which is my Uk and Irish water boundaries (EEZ) from marine regions.com, I have tried clipping, intersect and select by location to try and limit the polygons to just my boundary, but it just highlights the species that intersect with this boundary and still shows their whole global range/distribution. When I clipped it I had my input layer as the as my marine mammal export which contains the 24 marine species which intersect with with boundary and then I had the clip feature as my UK boundary but when the clip is complete it’s just empty.

As well as this all the polygons are overlapping and jumping I’ve tried a minimum convex tool to try shrink the polygons but that didn’t work at all.

Comment: Clipping sounds like what you need.  What are the precise and detailed steps that you performed when you got stuck with that?

Comment: Hi, when I clipped it I had my input layer as the as my marine mammal export which contains the 24 marine species which intersect with with boundary and then I had the clip feature as my UK boundary but when the clip is complete it’s just empty.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications. I suspect you may have an incorrect spatial reference on one of your datasets so I think you should look at their Properties to see if the coordinate values seem sensible for their spatial references.